# Cordova Android 6.4.0 creates res folder top level not inside platforms android

Tags: android, cordova, build, icons, splash-screen

After upading cordova and my project from 6.3.1 to 6.4.0, when I build the Android version, it generates the res folder with splash screens and icons files, at top level of the project, instead of at platforms/android/res where it should. Thus my app has the default cordova icons and splash screens instead of mine.

Is this a bug in the new Cordova version? Does anyone know of a setting that could prevent this? It was working ok when I used 6.3.1 .

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12077. It has been fixed and will be released as soon as possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is solved in `cordova-android 6.1.0` but if you try `cordova platform update android` at this moment doesn't update to `6.1.0`.

Run

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.0 --save
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

to solve this issue.

Some people seem to still have the issue after the command above... Try:

```
cordova platform update android@6.2.0-nightly.2016.12.9.6c60dc5d --save
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

You can also try:
    android@latest ....

Also try:
    ionic resources --icon

I'm using that version and it works, let me know if it solved the problem...

Comment: For me, upgrading to Android 6.1.0 didn't change anything. I had to downgrade Cordova to 6.3.1.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps are you sure? cordova-android 6.1.0 should have the problem solved... https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/compare/6.0.0...master CB-12077

Comment: I'll try again but I'm pretty sure. I first tried to update to 6.1.0, then I completely uninstalled Android and reinstalled it in 6.1.0. Both ways didn't work.

Comment: same issue here

Comment: IanO.S. and @SimonDéchamps I've updated the answer ... try it now and let me know....

Comment: @RodrigoGraça A few days ago I tried updating Cordova to 6.4.0 and Android platform to 6.1.0 and it worked (I have my app icon). But my co-worker installed the same versions from scratch and he has Cordova icon. May it work for me because I downgraded Cordova to 6.3.1 before upgrading it again, so the thing that didn't work for me in 6.4.0 in the first place still doesn't work but at least didn't erase what 6.3.1 did about the icon? Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I have 6.5.0 and it copied the res folders inside the root/res instead of platform one.

Comment: @RodrigoGraça Somehow it still does not work :( I have android 6.1.2 should I try downgrading to 6.1.0?

Comment: @JuanCarlos maybe... make sure you remove and add the platform again ... also remove the res folder to check if its recreated

Comment: Worked with android@latest (corresponds with 6.1.2 on writing this). But had to remove all, delete everything and git pull again, then install from scratch. Maybe something was corrupted.
Thanks for your time mate. +1

Answer (score 3):

after updating to cordova 6.4.0

cordova platform update android@6.1.0 --save
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android

did not fix the issue for me,
I had to manually copy the resources from res to android/res

Comment: I can confirm that.

Comment: I can confirm this.